# npm node_modules not being properly nested?

Tags: npm

I'm getting unexpected behavior when using npm. For example when installing express with the command:

```
npm install express
```

I would expect that a folder named, "express" would be created in the "node_modules" directory and that it's dependencies would be installed within a "node_modules" sub-directory within this folder.

What I am seeing is that the "express" folder is being created but all of it's dependencies are being added to the root "node_modules" directory (same level as express) in my project folder and not nested within the "express" folder.

Why is this happening? (using npm v3.3.5)

Comment: in case nesting is preferred: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35227212/580651

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a design change for npm@3, it deduplicates by default. See:

> Flat, flat, flat!
>
> Your dependencies will now be installed *maximally flat*.  Insofar as is
>   possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and THEIR
>   dependencies will be installed in your project's `node_modules` folder with no
>   nesting.  You'll only see modules nested underneath one another when two (or
>   more) modules have conflicting dependencies.

https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/ff47bc138e877835f1c0f419fea5f5672110678a/CHANGELOG.md#flat-flat-flat

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6912

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! I figured it was either a config option or a change but couldn't find it on my google quest :]

Comment: Is there any way to get the nested dependencies back? I mean, am getting into gulp and am strike with 131 directories all over my node modules folder. Its really overwhelming and makes me frustrated.

Comment: @5parc What's the connection between the directory structure and getting into gulp? In what context are you looking at the directory structure and getting overwhelmed?

Comment: It was mainly because all the tutorials out there covered gulp pre NPM 3.0, back in the day dependencies would be nested. But I figured out its just a structural change & realized it would work pretty much the same.

Comment: @5parc Yeah it's mostly an implementation detail that you shouldn't have to worry about too much (though it should save you from having to run `npm dedupe`).

Comment: @5parc in case you still want them nested: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35227212/580651