# Avoiding package duplicates in node_modules after versions have been aligned

Tags: npm

Here's an example: in my project

`npm ls | grep radium`

yielded

`│ └─┬ radium@0.18.1
├─┬ radium@0.17.2`

that is, I depended on a certain version of radium and on a package (say `x`) that itself depended on an other version of radium.

After running

`npm update`

The above command yielded:

`│ └─┬ radium@0.18.1
├─┬ radium@0.18.1`

which is not the expected behavior. In fact I had to remove `x` and reinstall it to achieve this:

`├─┬ radium@0.18.1`

Now I wonder whether this is a bug, or whether there is a way I can make sure this doesn't happen with other packages.

Answer (score 1):

`npm dedupe` is the answer

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe

"Description

Searches the local package tree and attempts to simplify the overall structure by moving dependencies further up the tree, where they can be more effectively shared by multiple dependent packages."

Also, the newer npm versions flatten the node_modules folder so it won't even be necessary. See this question: [npm node_modules not being properly nested?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926251/npm-node-modules-not-being-properly-nested)