# How to ignore scoped packages' node_modules/ directory during npm install?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a repository containing a `package.json` which contains scoped dependencies. I also have an `.npmignore` file intended to whitelist all files and subdirectories in `dist/`. The problem is all of the scoped dependencies are included when running `npm install @private/a` another repository. This includes both private npm packages and public packages such as @uirouter.

package.json:

```
   {
      "name": "@private/a",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "dist/index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/private/a.git"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/private/a#readme",
      "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-angular-embed-templates": "^2.3.0",
        "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
        "gulp-jshint": "^2.0.4",
        "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
        "gulp-sass": "^3.0.0",
        "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
        "jshint": "^2.9.4"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@private/b": "^1.0.0",
        "@private/c": "^1.0.0"
      }
    }
```

.npmignore

```
**
!dist/**
```

Despite these two files when I run `npm install @private/a --save` within another repository it is installing the dependency along with all it's scoped dependencies:

```
/node_modules/@private/a/dist/index.js
/node_modules/dist/css/styles.css
/node_modules/@private/a/node_modules/@private/b
/node_modules/@private/a/node_modules/@private/c
package.json
```

It should only be this:

```
/node_modules/@private/a/dist/index.js
/node_modules/dist/css/styles.css
package.json
```

How can I achieve this? I have tried different variations of the `.npmignore` but have not had any luck.

Comment: Are `@private/b` and `@private/c` required for your package `@private/a` to run?

Comment: Or they are required only during `@private/a` development and building, do they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.npmignore` is irrelevant to what you are trying to do. This file only decides which parts of your npm package code ends up in npm registry. So it is working as advertised.

Your problem must be in your npmconfig or because of using an older version of npm. The latest version installs stuff as so:

```
/node_modules/@private/a/dist/index.js
/node_modules/@private/b/...
/node_modules/@private/c/...
package.json
```

I have verified that this is happening with latest npm. But there used to be a time when npm installed dependencies into a nested structure. See [this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33154836/npm-install-installs-all-dependencies-in-node-modules-directory-instead-of-ha#35227212). So I suggest:

1. Making sure you have latest node and npm.
2. Making sure your npm config is not forcing legacy bundling. Run `npm get legacy-bundling`. Make sure this is false.

There are few cases where the nesting of dependencies happens legitimately even with the latest npm. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926251/npm-node-modules-not-being-properly-nested?noredirect=1&lq=1). But I am guessing your problem is not due to this. You can test by simply doing `npm install @private/a` in an empty folder.

Comment: This was the problem, thanks! I was using npm version 3, and in version 5 this is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Node will install your package files along with all the dependencies declared under `dependencies` field.

How the dependencies tree is build, depends on which version of `npm` do you use.

If your package doesn't need those dependencies to run, it means they are just dev dependencies and you can safely list them under `devDependencies` field.

Dev dependencies are only installed when you run an `npm install` inside the plugin directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to lock your dependency. You might want to check out [`npm shrinkwrap`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap).